# Silverlight: Apply effect on all items that match some criteria in an ItemsControl

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, mvvm, itemscontrol, mouseenter

I'm loading images dynamically onto a Canvas based on some data I receive from the back end. I have a data structure that looks like this:

```
ID: 1  GROUP: A  X: 10  Y: 10
ID: 2  GROUP: A  X: 20  Y: 20
ID: 3  GROUP: A  X: 30  Y: 30
ID: 4  GROUP: B  X: 40  Y: 40
ID: 5  GROUP: B  X: 50  Y: 50
ID: 6  GROUP: C  X: 60  Y: 60
```

I'm loading this data into an `ItemsControl` that looks something like this:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding MyDataSet}">
  <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <Canvas>
        <Image Height="10" Width="10" 
               Source="/someImage.png" 
               Canvas.Left="{Binding X}" 
               Canvas.Top="{Binding Y}" 
               MouseEnter="Image_MouseEnter"
               MouseLeave="Image_MouseLeave" />
      </Canvas>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

The images are showing up on the `Canvas` just fine. When the user places their mouse over an image, the `Image_MouseEnter` event handler replaces the image with another "highlighted" image. The `Image_MouseLeave` method swaps the images back. This is also working fine.

What I **want** to do is also use the "highlighted" image for each other image that has the same `GROUP` as the image has hovered over. So if I place my mouse over the image for `ID: 1  GROUP: A`, it should swap out the images for IDs 2 and 3.

Just to make things more interesting, I'm also using MVVM. :)

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds pretty straightforward to me. I would do the following:

1. Wrap each of of your data items in a view-model, `DataItemViewModel`. And place them within an `ObservableCollection`.
2. Create a relationship between `DataItemViewModel` and the collection that holds them, so that you can navigate from the child to the parent.
3. Bind the `Image.Source` property to the `DataItemViewModel`. You will need this so that you can swap the source when the image is highlighted.
4. Handle your mouse enter / leave events in code-behind (yes, this is allowed in MVVM!).
5. On mouse-enter, change the `DataItemViewModel` state to highlighted (perhaps expose a boolean `IsHighlighted` property), and use this to change the image source. Also, navigate back to the parent collection so that you can find all other `DataItemViewModel` instances that mach your criteria and set their highlighted state to true as well.

Hope that help!